# Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, doctrine-2

estou com um probleminha quando tento executar minha aplicação , pois então tenho uma aplicação feita com **doctrine + php** e de uns tempos para cá começou a dar esse erro segue:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) 
 in /home/mentorsitescom/public_html/prefeituraexemplo/mpe-serv-sol-desenv/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php on line 236
```

Eu já tentei setar via php o limite da memoria para:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

ou para

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Só que ainda continua o erro, alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Já tentou identificar o que está consumindo tanto a memória?

Comment: boa pergunta vou verificar